# stuck at storing math’s equation in database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I am developing MCQ generator desktop application in asp.net(c#), but I m stuck at storing math’s equation in database (i.e. SQL Server 2005) and displaying it to UI, can any one help me out as soon as possible please. I want to save [this](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Byut71lsgtF_cnoxenNWaVJUUlk)  type of math expression.

Comment: Using ASAP in question is never a good idea

Comment: What is the math equation in?  String, object?  If you need a quick answer, provide the necessary details would help achieve the goal.

Comment: Please add an example of math function in the question.

Comment: Which kind of equations are you talking about? please describe your question in more details and provide necessary code/functions.

Comment: I don't have any idea, i have tried it with 'reachtextbox' and 'nvarchar' datatype in sql but sql stores blank value only. n yes sooo sorryy for not reading "How to Ask",

Answer (score 0):

Use `MathML` for this. See some examples [here](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/mathml-samples/)

Comment: The OP is not after equations, the OP wants code to `store data in the dB then retrieve it and render it  on a ASPX page.` - the words highlighted would be the google solution...